# Filter through files in GCS bucket folder and delete 0 byte files with Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam

I am currently trying to delete all the files that are 0 Bytes within a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I want to be able to do this with apache beam and a dataflow runner that will run on
a google cloud project. What I have right now is this (I have hidden some details with `<***>`):

```
import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem as gcs
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

class DetectEmpty(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, file_path):
        if gfs.size(file_path) == 0:
            yield file_path

def run(argv=None):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input', dest='input', default=<***>, help='<***>')

    options = PipelineOptions()
    google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    google_cloud_options.project = '<***>'
    google_cloud_options.job_name = '<***>'
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'

    gfs = gcs.GCSFileSystem(pipeline_options)
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    images = p | 'read directory' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)
    empty_images = images | 'discover empty files' >> beam.ParDo(DetectEmpty())

    p.run()
```

Some of my questions are:

- Is this the right way to go about doing this task?
- How do I pass the `apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.GCSFileSystem` to the `DoFn`?
- Furthermore I want to go about deleting all the folders that contain just files that are 0 bytes. How would I go about that?

Comment: Why are you deleting not billable files? Do you have many? Did they slow you other processes?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere There are quite a sizeable amount of 0B files. It's not about billing, it's about people browsing the bucket and not finding anything useful due to there being a very small percentage of non 0 byte files.

Comment: Did you try to build a script with [this feature](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du). Run it all the night long on your computer or a VM, it could as efficient and performant as Dataflow.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere scripts are a great option, but the data is actually quite big. Plus, if this is eventually supposed to be integrated into airflow, I would prefer dataflow jobs over scripts, due to integration with GCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to actually read the files in order to detect empty ones, you can just use the FileSystem object directly to check the file sizes and delete as needed.  The FileMetadata object returned by the match() function includes the size of the files.

Something like

```
class DeleteEmpty(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, gfs):
    self.gfs = gfs

  def process(self, file_metadata):
    if file_metadata.size_in_bytes == 0:
      gfs.delete([file_metadata.path])

files = p | 'Filenames' >> beam.Create(gfs.match([<directory glob pattern>]).metadata_list)
          | 'Reshuffle' >> beam.Reshuffle() # this allows the downstream code to be parallelized after the Create
          | 'Delete empty files' >> beam.ParDo(DeleteEmpty(gfs))
```

GCS doesn't really have folders; they are just a convenience added when using the UI or gsutil.  When there are no objects in a folder, that folder just doesn't exist.  See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork

Comment: So I just tried this out and seem to be getting the error: 

`raise ValueError('GCS path must be in the form gs://<bucket>/<object>.')`, so I decided to print out the input going into `parse_gcs_path()`, and it seems like it is only the very first character `g`from the string that contains `gcs://xxx/xxx`?

Comment: Sorry, match takes a list of globs, not a single one.  Edited the answer to reflect that

Comment: Furthermore we have: 

  `File "delete0B_dataflow.py", line 36, in <module>
    delete_empty_files()
  File "delete0B_dataflow.py", line 30, in delete_empty_files
    'Reshuffle' >> beam.Reshuffle() | \
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'metadata_list'
`

Comment: Okay, resolved that by using `gfs.match([gs_folder])[0].metadata_list`, now am getting the error `WARNING:apache_beam.options.pipeline_options:Discarding unparseable args: ['gs://xx/xx']` which is in fact my input arg