# List folders by size on gcs bucket with dataflow

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

Looking through the code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66086511/filter-through-files-in-gcs-bucket-folder-and-delete-0-byte-files-with-dataflow/66107294#66107294) question, I want to be able to create a dataflow pipeline that can look at all the files within a specific gcs bucket folder and state the final subdirectories with the greatest amount of data in terms of bytes. I would write code that is similar to :

```
class SortFiles(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, gfs):
    self.gfs = gfs

  def process(self, file_metadata):
    if file_metadata.size_in_bytes > 0:
      # Sort the files here? 


class SortFolders(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, gfs):
    self.gfs = gfs

  def process(self, file_metadata):
    if file_metadata.size_in_bytes > 0:
      # Sort the folders here based on maximum addition of a combination 
      # of the file sizes and file numbers 


def delete_empty_files():

    options = PipelineOptions(...)

    gfs = gcs.GCSFileSystem(pipeline_options)
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    discover_empty = p | 'Filenames' >> beam.Create(gfs.match(gs_folder).metadata_list)
                        | 'Reshuffle' >> beam.Reshuffle() 
                        | 'SortFilesbySize' >> beam.ParDo(SortFiles(gfs))
                        | 'SortFoldersbySize' >> beam.ParDo(SortFolders(gfs))
                        | 'OutputFolders' >> ...
```

I have not decided on whether to list the folders by the total amount of bytes or the total number of files within them. How would I go about solving this issue? Another issue lies in the fact that I want to be able to find the final sub directory and not its parent folders for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GCSFileSystem` has a function, `du` that will tell you the size under a particular path. https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=du#gcsfs.core.GCSFileSystem

In reading your question I think you want to

1. first find all directories within the bucket that do not themselves contain directories (if I understand 'final subdirectories')
2. then run `du` on each of them,
3. then sort that resulting list on size

If you are trying to do a count of files nested:

1. list all objects, names will be a/, a/b.txt, a/b/c.txt, etc
2. write a function to count the objects nested under each sub path